# CodeIgniter 500 server error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a question that has had me pulling my hair over the last few weeks.. i have been having a blast developing a `Codeigniter` website on my local machine and everything functions as normal on the local machine, however when i upload the site to the production server then the links stop working and whenever clicked give me a 500 internal server error also ajax post requests also generate a 500 internal error from the console. I m really stumped as to what the problem could be thats why i have come to ask here, could anybody help me please. Also i don't have shell access
this is my `htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It looks like you are new here, welcome! Did you check the related answers on the right side?

Comment: Do you have rewrite module active on your server ?

Comment: yep i did i will just confirm if rewrite module is available

Comment: post your config settings for uri_protocol

Comment: my config settings for uri protocol are default i tried all the alternatives provided to no avail so  just returned them to AUTO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this as .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^sys.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^app.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

assumming that **index.php** is your index page.

and change in config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

if you are using sub domain set it as the **RewriteBase**

Comment: am greatful this htacces seems to work. can u please tell me whwt was wrong with my htaccess?